# Can spaces behave like tabs on backspace in vim?

Tags: vim

I have these configures in vimrc file:

```
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

But if I press backspace, I wanna delete whole tab (4 spaces).

Answer (score 3):

Add the following:

```
set softtabstop=4
```

The documentation on tabstops and soft tabstops is comprehensive and I recommend reviewing it. In summary, in this scenario, adding the softtabstop parameter will cause vim to treat this many spaces *as if* it were a single tab character.